# How to get the souce code from Git/Mercurial repository using Bitbucket/SourceTree to a specific date

Tags: git, mercurial, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I would like to ask you for an advice about Mercurial/GIT repository which is hosted on Bitbucket.org server. I am using either web-interface via Bitbucket.org or SourceTree app for managing my sources/commits.

Now I need **download to my local folder full set of my sources to a specific date**, but there is no idea how to reach it.

Please, can you advice me, how to get full set of my sources which was valid to a specific day (for example 10 days ago)? Which tool may I use? Which action?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Regards
Radek Budař

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command "checkout" is the best choise for it.

With using of SourceTree you can go to the Log/History tab, there you have to find a commit to which you you want go back, select it and click by right mouse button. Then choose "checkout" and confirm next warning dialog.

SourceTree will update your sources on your local disk to this commit (allsources in whole project will be affected). Don't worry, you will be able to make a checkout to the last commit as well. But be aware, that all changes from your local disk MUST BE commited before this action.

Best regards
Radek Budař